# loop through nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

I wish to loop through the following json dictionary:

```
hgetjsonObject = {
    u 'jsonrpc': u '2.0', u 'result': [{
        u 'hosts': [{
            u 'status': u '0',
            u 'hostid': u '10394',
            u 'name': u 'vsclap01l'
        }, {
            u 'status': u '0',
            u 'hostid': u '10395',
            u 'name': u 'vsclap03l'
        }, {
            u 'status': u '0',
            u 'hostid': u '10396',
            u 'name': u 'vscldb04l'
        }],
        u 'groupid': u '4',
        u 'name': u 'Zabbix servers'
    }], u 'id': 2
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
print(hgetjsonObject['result'][0]['hosts'][0])
```

But when I run it, it aborts with the following:

```
{u'status': u'0', u'hostid': u'10394', u'name': u'vsclap01l'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automaton.py", line 341, in <module>
    print(hgetjsonObject['result'][0]['hosts'][0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
for eachhost in hgjsonObject['result']:
    print(eachhost['hostid'],eachhost['name'])
```

When I run the for loop, I get errors.

Comment: `print(eachhost['hosts'][0]["hostid"],eachhost['hosts'][0]["name"])`

Comment: `print(hgetjsonObject['result'][0]['hosts'][0])` runs without any error. can you show us file `automaton.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.
1) there is space between u an field in your dictionary which will cause issue.

2) because result is a list and under that hosts is another list, you should iterate through both the lists

```
for eachresult in hgetjsonObject['result']:
         for eachhost in eachresult['hosts']:
             print(eachhost['hostid'],eachhost['name'])
```

Output:

10394 vsclap01l
10395 vsclap03l
10396 vscldb04l

Answer (score 0):

for access to `hosts` key iterate in this way:

```
>>> for eachhost in hgetjsonObject['result'][0]['hosts']:
        print(eachhost["hostid"], eachhost["name"])

('10394', 'vsclap01l')
('10395', 'vsclap03l')
('10396', 'vscldb04l')
```